# PHP MYSQL select customers with birthdays between a range of a given 2 months

Tags: php, mysql

I have a customers table with birthday field (of type `date`).
I also have 2 dates, lets say `date1="10/17/2015"` and `date2="10/31/2015"`.
I want to select all customers with birthdays between the given month/day of any year.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I Solved using this query:
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(birthdate),2,'0'), LPAD(DAYOFMONTH(birthdate),2,'0')) BETWEEN ? AND ?

Comment: You can submit that as the answer (use literals instead of variables), and 'accept' it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CONCAT(LPAD(MONTH(birthdate),2,'0'), LPAD(DAYOFMONTH(birthdate),2,'0')) BETWEEN 1017 AND 1031
```

where the (1017, 1031) is the concat of the MonthDay from the posted dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE bday BETWEEN "2015-10-01" AND "2015-11-01"
```

Comment: this will select the birthdays from the current year only.

Comment: @AmjadAta-Allah That's why you will be passing these dates from PHP side. `date('Y-m-01')`/`date('Y-').(date('m')+1).'-01'`

Answer (score 0):

use mysql **STR_TO_DATE** with **BETWEEN**

```
    SELECT * FROM customer WHERE bday BETWEEN 
    STR_TO_DATE('10/17/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND 
    STR_TO_DATE('10/31/2015','%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: The point is that i want to select all customers with birthdates of any year between the given month and day from date1, date2

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer WHERE bday BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('10/17/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('10/31/2015','%m/%d/%Y') try this @AmjadAta-Allah

Comment: this will select all birthdates between the given dates in the same year. What i need is to select the birthdates between the given 2 dates (month/day) in any year

Comment: This will also select only the customers with birthdays in between the given years

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT * FROM customes WHERE birth_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('10/17/2015','%m/%d/%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('10/31/2015','%m/%d/%y');
```